# Exporting PDF in Inkscape doesnt work correctly

Tags: print-design, inkscape, pdf, export, scribus

I created an Inkscape document but the background is a colored square. The border around the text is a square with rounded corners and the text is normal text but the "scratches" are created through a mask with a png.

[image: in scribus]

When I export this document as a PDF, the resulting PDF looks like this:

[image: exported pdf]

Why am I only getting a partial export?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Incomplete image when exporting SVG from Inkscape](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/137559/incomplete-image-when-exporting-svg-from-inkscape)

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say, without being able to see the `.svg` file.

My supposition is that you're using a PDF version (PDF 1.3? PDF x-1a?) that does not support transparencies.
Have you tried exporting as PDF 1.4?

And what does a "real" PDF viewer (like Adobe Reader) show?
(As the name says, Apple's Preview is "just" a fast preview tool)

Anyway, I don't understand why some of the scratches are still visible in the rounded rectangle.
Are they also produced by a PNG?

There are good chances that the PDF export is working in the way it's supposed to work, but some of the features you're trying to use are not compatible with the settings you have chosen.

Would it be possible for you to upload the `.svg` file or a sample `.svg` file that shows the issue so that we can have a try at it?

Comment: Sorry, I messed up Scribus and Inkscape completely. Its an Inkscape Document :-/

Comment: Well, then you should consider, posting the SVG or a sample SVG... The remarks about the PDF versions and the Viewer are valid for Inkscape, too.

Comment: So? Did you find a solution?