# Incomplete image when exporting SVG from Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, svg

Thank you for your answers in advance.

I have the following image in inkscape, which has no layers (the background is usually white).

[image: desired image]

When I export to Optimised SVG it appears incomplete (and seemingly randomly).

[image: incomplete image]

I have tried changing the groups, from ungrouping everything, to grouping it all in one, but this just results in varying incomplete images. I have tried changing the decimal places from 6 to 5, ticked and unticked the 'collapse groups' and the tick below.

What am I doing wrong to cause the image to export incorrectly as an optimised SVG file. I cannot use PNG or PDF as the web designer has asked for SVG specifically.

Again, thank you in advance, and if you need more details then let me know.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. This is difficult to answer without access to the SVG, and will depend on how it was constructed.  Some things to try: make sure there are no path effects, and try not to use any filters if at all possible, also try exporting as "Plain SVG" as the file type. These are usually the cause of such problems. Also make sure you are viewing the SVG in a recent/up-to-date browser.

Comment: @BillyKerr Thanks! There are no path effects or filters, I am viewing in the most up to date browser and exporting as plain SVG didn't change anything. How do I add the SVG file so that you can see it?

Comment: @BillyKerr I just tried copying the image that is correct when seen in inkscape and pasting it into Krita (another drawing software), and it resulted in the same incomplete image as if I open the save file in a browser. I am not sure if this is useful information.

Comment: You can share an SVG image on SVGshare, and post the link.

Comment: @BillyKerr Here you go. This is the incomplete version. https://svgshare.com/i/LH4.svg

Comment: I see you have a lot of clipping masks set. Not sure why there are clipping masks on all the circles in the background, but that's probably the issue.  I tried releasing the big green one, and removing the white filled mask. And then it worked when viewed in the browser.  How did you create these circles?

Comment: @BillyKerr Hi Billy. Great that it is working! I put the mask to crop the image to fit into the yellow border - the veg around the edge peeks out the edges otherwise. Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: @BillyKerr I created the circles just using circle tool. 

Once I had created the background, I grouped it together, then used the white mask to crop it so that it fit behind the frame. This seems to be causing the issues (and removing it is very time consuming - I have 60 of these to do!)

Comment: Yeah there are issues with some Inkscape SVG features not being support in browsers. Best not to use clipping masks to construct anything. Keep it simple - just shapes, strokes and fills, nothing fancy. If you must cut something, use boolean operations.

Comment: @BillyKerr ah! That might just work! Thanks Billy!

Comment: Also the big yellow filled circle should cover up the vegetables overlapping, so there was no need to use a clipping mask anyway.

Comment: Yeah it does in this one (other than the onion leaves), but I have several others where the background goes outside of the frame, so I will try using Boolean operations to sort those. Thank you!

Comment: I've added an answer now, summarising the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking the SVG, the issue seems to be multiple clipping masks throughout the design - especially those background elements and blocks of colour.

There are issues with some Inkscape SVG features not being supported in browsers, and it appears clipping masks are one of those features.

What I suggest you do is release those clipping masks, and instead construct the image using nothing other than paths with strokes, and fills.  If you must cut up objects, use boolean operations instead.

Note also that you can use simple filled shapes to hide overlaps without the need for clipping masks.